# Splitting factors in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a factor with values of the form `Single (w/children)`, `Married (no children)`, `Single (no children)`, etc. and would like to split these into two factors, one multi-valued factor for marital status, and binary-valued one for children.

How do I do this in R?

Comment: Is the marital status always first in the string with children second?

Comment: @user20650: Yes, sometimes two words like `Domestic Partners`; and occasionally just a null value (`""`) which I'd like to treat as `NA`.

Comment: Are you asking how to split strings in R? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some example data

```
df <- data.frame(status=c("Domestic partners (w/children)", "Married (no
  children)", "Single (no children)"))
```

Get married status out of string. This assumes that marital status is the first word in the character string. If not, you could do it using `grepl`

```
df$married <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$status) , " \\(") , "[" , 1)

# Change to factor
df$married <- factor(df$married , levels=c("Single" , "Married", 
                                                 "Domestic partners"))
```

Get child status out of string

```
df$ch <- ifelse(grepl("no children" , df$status) , 0 , 1)
```

---

A bit more info

This splits each element where there is a " (" - you need to escape the '(' with \\ as it is a special character.

```
s <- strsplit(as.character(df$status) , " \\(")
```

We then subset this by selecting the first term

```
sapply(s , "[" , 1)
```

The `grepl` looks for the string "no children" and return a TRUE or FALSE

```
grepl("no children" , df$status)
```

We use an ifelse to dichotomise

---

**EDIT**

Re comment: adding in some empty strings ("") to data [Note: rather than having empty strings it is generally better to have these as missing (NA). You can do this when you are reading in the data ie. in `read.table` you can use the `na.strings` argument (na.strings=c(NA,"")].

```
    df <- data.frame(status=c("Domestic partners (w/children)", "Married 
   (no children)", "Single (no children)",""))
```

The command for married status works but the `grepl` and ifelse will not. As a quick fix you could add this after the ifelse.

```
df$ch[df$status==""] <- NA
```

or if you manage to set empty strings to missing

```
df$ch[is.na(df$status)] <- NA
```

Run the commands above and this gives

```
#                          status           married ch
# 1 Domestic partners (w/children) Domestic partners  1
# 2          Married (no children)           Married  0
# 3           Single (no children)            Single  0
# 4                                             <NA> NA
```

Comment: In both columns I have `""` values that I'd like to treat as missing. Is there a way to modify the above to do that?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius;  If you could could edit your question with example data (like i did in the example: df$status) I'll try and update

Comment: I think I'll ask that as a separate question so I can accept this answer. (It's kind of chaining the question after you've already answered it.)